# Match a set of data in a csv file with multiple csv files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I would like to take a set of data (a single csv file) to search the data that matched in multiple csv files.

The algorithm as below:

1. Take the data from a single csv file.
2. Add the path for multiple csv files.
3. Open the file and read the entire row
4. If the data(single csv) is match, will print out the entire row

```
from csv import reader
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

#Get the name from csv
a_list=["Name"]
a = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Master.csv", usecols=a_list)
a.reset_index(inplace=True)

#Path for multiple csv
path = r"C:\Users\DeliveryReport"
data_file = glob.glob(os.path.join(path + "/part*.csv"))

#Get the entire row if first column same as the name get from csv
for filename in data_file:
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding="utf8") as read_obj:
        print(filename)
        csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
        header = next(csv_reader)
        if header != None:
            for row in csv_reader:
                i = 0
                for i in range(len(a)):
                    if row[0] == a.iloc[i,1]:
                        print(row)
```

Comment: Try printing out what ```row``` is before the ```if row[0] == a[i]:```.

Comment: Any chance you have an empty file there?

Comment: @ewong the output is Name

Comment: @pavel nope, I have check the csv files

Comment: One of the files has a blank line. Most likely at the end of the file. Change to `if len(row)>0 and row[0] == a[i]:`.

Comment: @AlexPhang  Please include the actual output when you put ```print(row)``` before ```if row[0] == a[i]:```

Comment: @DYZ it still showing the same error

Comment: @ewong yes, I did. Due to I put ```print(row[0])```, so the output is Name. If ```print(row)```, the output would be ```Name, Age, Address, Origin```.

Comment: No, I meant put the ```print(row)``` before the ```if row[0] == a[i]:``` and then run your script.   Then include the results in your post.

Comment: I have tried to put ```print(a[i])```, it shows the error is there, ```a``` type is DataFrame, is there any wrong on this?

Comment: Ok, now you try to compare the whole column of your DataFrame with one value from the `row`.  Something is wrong with your application logic.

Comment: @DYZ After I updated the ```a.iloc[i,1]```, I got ```UnicodeDecodeError```. After researched from internet, I found that when open and read the file, it required ```encoding="utf8"``` to resolve the error. UTF-8 is about 8-bit blocks, why do it requires to encode in my csv files? all of them are in string.